# jest enzyme test method in componentDidMount fails but console shows that it is working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Inside my `componentDidMount()` I am calling `this.loadData()` if a couple functions return true, which they do. I have console logs throughout my code which prove to me that it is calling the function, however Jest is saying that it wasn't called at all.

Notice my `console.log` of the following steps.

1. componentDidMount
2. drilldown evaluated true
3. response not empty

**componentDidMount()**

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');

    if(props.drilldown) {
        console.log('drilldown');

        // emptyObject is a helper function that makes sure
        // modifiedState.response !== {}

        if(!emptyObject(modifiedState.response)) {
            console.log('response not empty');

            this.loadData(modifiedState.response, modifiedState.lastUpdated);
        }
    }
}
```

When `loadData()` is called I have 3 more `console.log` that are shown in my test output.

1. loadData was called
2. `data` that was passed
3. `updated` that was passed

**loadData**

```
loadData(data, updated) {
    console.log('loadData');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(updated);

    ... a bunch of other stuff here that doesn't matter
}
```

In my unit test I am setting the values which are being passed to `loadData` as follows.

1. `data` should evaluate to `{ table: [{}] }`
2. `updated` should evaluate to `'Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500'`

**unit test**

```
it('component mounts as expected', () => {

    const modifiedState = {
        ...parentState,
        lastUpdated: 'Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500',
        response: { table: [{}] }
    }

    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Chart
            chart='testChart'
            comparison='testComparison'
            drilldown={true}
            parentState={modifiedState} />
    );

    const loadData = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'loadData');

    expect(loadData).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ table: [{}] }, 'Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500');
    expect(loadData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    wrapper.unmount();
  });
```

The console output when running my test says that `loadData was not called` and the line that it is complaining about is

```
expect(loadData).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ table: [{}] }, 'Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500');
```

However if you continue scrolling you can see all of my `console.log` being called with the appropriate information. This tells me that it is actually working however something with Jest/Enzyme isn't right.

As a side note, I have 4 other functions inside `componentDidMount()` that pass just fine.

**console log output when running test**

```
 FAIL  src/components/Common/Chart.test.js
  ● Drilldown Chart › component mounts as expected

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      [{"table": [{}]}, "Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500"]

    But it was not called.

      at Object.fit (src/components/Common/Chart.test.js:140:22)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)

  Chart
    ○ skipped 1 test
  Drilldown Chart
    ✕ component mounts as expected (19ms)
    ○ skipped 11 tests
  Dashboard Chart
    ○ skipped 2 tests

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 14 skipped, 15 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.515s

Ran all test suites matching "src/components/Common/Chart.test.js".

  console.log src/components/Common/Chart.jsx:45
    componentDidMount

  console.log src/components/Common/Chart.jsx:75
    drilldown

  console.log src/components/Common/Chart.jsx:77
    response not empty

  console.log src/components/Common/Chart.jsx:134
    loadData

  console.log src/components/Common/Chart.jsx:135
    { table: [ {} ] }

  console.log src/components/Common/Chart.jsx:136
    Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500
```

Comment: You're creating the spy _after_ the component has been mounted and so _after_ `loadData` has been called. So, `loadData` is being called as your console logs show, but it's being called before your spy is created and so the test fails because the spy'd version of it was never called.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, so the correct way to do this would be to put `const loadData = jest.spyOn(Chart.prototype, 'loadData');` just above where I use `shallow`? 

If you post a more expanded answer then I would mark yours as correct since it is the cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthew Herbst was correct about the order of things.

You could do this instead:

```
it('component mounts as expected', () => {

    const modifiedState = {
        ...parentState,
        lastUpdated: 'Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500',
        response: { table: [{}] }
    }

    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Chart
            chart='testChart'
            comparison='testComparison'
            drilldown={true}
            parentState={modifiedState} />,
        { disableLifecycleMethods: true }
    );
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    const loadData = jest.spyOn(instance, 'loadData');
    instance.componentDidMount()

    expect(loadData).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ table: [{}] }, 'Wed Dec 26 2018 13:26:03 GMT-0500');
    expect(loadData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    wrapper.unmount();
  });
```

Here, I disabled lifecycle methods with `{ disableLifecycleMethods: true }`.  Then, I manually call `componentDidMount` after setting up the spy.

It's a little tacky, but it could work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your way also works. I had tried putting the `spyOn` above my shallow before but it always complained about being undefined. Turns out I was just missing `prototype`.